# how do i resolve 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' error, when i use npm ./ on ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, npm

[image: here's the error message]

here's the code

```
const {ethers} = require("ethers");

const INFURA_ID=''

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(`https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/${INFURA_ID}`)

const address = '0xDAFEA492D9c6733ae3d56b7Ed1ADB60692c98Bc5'

const main = async () => {
    const balance = await provider.getBalance(address)
    console.log(`\nEth balance of ${address} --> ${ethers.utils.formatEther(balance)} ETH\n`)
}

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

i was able to fix it by adding an extra dot(.)

```
here's what i mean: npm ../ETHERS_EXAMPLES/1_accounts.js instead of ./ETHERS_EXAMPLES/1_accounts.js
```

thanks.